# Why do I get False from the print(same(p) function? I should get True

Tags: python

I think I should get True, but I am getting False and can not understand why. Thanks in advance for looking into this.

```
def game(name, mix, good, notgood, allv):
    return str(name), tuple(mix), list(good), list(notgood), list(allv)


def create_game(name, mix):
    return game(name, mix, gap(mix), gap(mix, 0), gap(mix, 1))


def gap(ltras, *args):
    temp = []
    if len(args) == 0:
        temp.append("ABCD")
    if len(args) == 1 and args[0] == 0:
        temp.append("A")
    if len(args) == 1 and args[0] == 1:
        temp.append("AB")
    temp.sort()
    temp.sort(key=len)
    return temp


def same(myobj):
    return isinstance(myobj, type(game))


ourmix = ("T", "E", "S", "T")
p = create_game("ALFA", ourmix)
print(same(p))
```

Comment: `type(game)` is function, `type(p)` (which you pass to isinstance) is the return value of that function (a tuple)

Comment: What return are you talking about? Which function?

Comment: return of create_game ... which is a call to game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's false is because 'game' is a function, whereas p is what the function 'game' returns, which is a tuple.

So essentially you are checking if a tuple (variable p) is an instance of function, which is what type(game) evaluates to.

If you wanted to use isinstance in this way, you could create a class called game and check isinstance(p,game), or in a function like you have it, isinstance(myobj,game).